# Using input over a range of types

Tags: sas

I have a very large dataset where every value is stored as a character. Many of the variables are actually numeric. I know I can convert to numeric by using:

```
new = input(old, BEST12.);
```

However if I apply this to a variable that contains text the value goes to missing. Is there a function that converts to numeric if it is applicable, otherwise it leaves it as a character?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to decide for yourself which variables can be converted to a number and which cannot.  If you need help then run a SAS program to check the values and see if they can be converted.

```
data _null_;
  set have ;
  if (lengthn(strip(var1)) > 32)
  or (not missing(var1) and missing(input(strip(var1),??32.))
    then do;
    put 'VAR1 cannot be converted to numeric because of value ' var1 :$quote. ;
    stop;
  end;
run;
```

NOTE: BEST is the name of a FORMAT, if you use it as an informat SAS will just use the normal numeric informat.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to two passes of the data in order to automatically convert applicable character columns to numeric columns.  The first evaluates and the second performs the conversion.

Example:

Between the measure and apply steps SQL is used to generated code snippets to be used in the conversion step.

```
data have;
  call streaminit(20230308);
  do row = 1 to 100;
    array x(10);
    length ab bc cd de ef fg gh hj jk kl lm np pq $20;
    array c ab--pq;
    do over c;
      c = cats(rand('uniform',1,50));

      if _i_ in (2, 6, 9) and row in (6, 33, 66, 77) then 
        c = 'I am not a number';

    end;
    output;
  end;
  keep row x: ab--pq;
run;

proc contents noprint data=have out=havec(keep=name type varnum length);
run;

* which characters columns contains only number representations ;

data col_isallnum;
  set have end=lastrow;
  array _c _character_;
  array _f (1000) _temporary_;
  do over _c;
    if _f(_i_) ne 1 then _f(_i_) = _c ne '.' and missing (input(_c,??best12.));
  end;

  if lastrow then do;
    do over _c;
      if _f(_i_) ne 1 then do;
        length name $32;
        name = vname (_c);
        output;
      end;
    end;    
  end;
  keep name;
run;

* generate code to maintain the original column order, but change the type of the 
* convertable columns from character to numeric (length=8);

proc sql noprint ;
  %let renames = ;
  %let attrs = ;
  %let conversions = ;

  select cats(name,'=_',varnum) into :renames separated by ' '
  from havec
  where name in (select name from col_isallnum)
  ;

  select cat(
    trim(A.name),
    case 
      when not missing(B.name) then ' length=8'
      when type = 2            then ' length=$' || cats(A.length)
                               else ' length='  || cats(A.length)
    end)
  into :attrs separated by ' '
  from havec A left join col_isallnum B on A.name = B.name
  ;

  select cats(A.name,'=input(_',A.varnum,',best12.)')
  into :conversions separated by ';'
  from havec A join col_isallnum B on A.name = B.name
  ;

quit;

* perform the conversions, codegen in the STEP will work even if no columns are convertible;

  data want;
    attrib &attrs;
    set have (rename=(&renames));
    &conversions;
  run;
```

Comment: Why only read the first 12 bytes of the string to check if it is a number?

Comment: Adjust as needed I suppose. BEST32. ? better.   And of course, **no** checks to see if representations in column are all date or datetime to be converted to SAS date or datetime as well

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. The Type of a SAS variable applies to the variable itself and all the values in it. You can not have some values of a variable stored as numeric and some as character.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear, I mean if all values of a variable can be converted to numeric without an error then do so, otherwise retain the whole variable as a character

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better informat to accomplish your goal, but you might also try using the anyalpha function to determine whether characters exist in the value first.

```
if anyalpha(desc) then new = old;
else new = input(old, BEST12.);
```

But the result is still a character value for the variable new. If you want to keep the numerics as true numerics, you could create a second new variable (new2) that is truly numeric.

```
if anyalpha(desc) then new = old;
else new2 = input(old, BEST12.);
```